# Tried to implement ActionMailer::Preview to preview email but get the error: No route matches [GET] "/rails/mailers" when I hit the previews url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actionmailer, preview, mailer

I have a straightforward mailer class in "app/mailers" directory.

`class SampleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def send_email 
      ...
    end
  end`

The corresponding "text" and "html" email templates are there in the corresponding "app/views/mailer" directory.

I created a mailerpreview class in "test/mailers/previews":

`class SampleMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def send_email
    ...
  end
end`

When I try to hit http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers I get a routing error...

I tried placing the mailer preview class in the lib/mailer_previews directory and configuring it in development.rb but still get the routing error...

Is there anything additional I would need to do in routes.rb to get email previewing to work? But as far as I understood about the email preview, we did not need to create a separate mailer controller...

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

also had this issue, the fix for me was to add this to my `config/<environment>.rb` file:

```
config.action_mailer.show_previews = true
```

Answer (score -1):

After you change your Mailer Preview file restart your rails server.

Answer (score -1):

In our application we had some like this in `routes.rb`:

`match "*path", :controller => "exceptions", :action => "no_route", :via => :all`

Apparently, this was the way to render 404 page with Rails 3.1 and earlier. When I removed this line, I was able to see email previews.